# How to trigger search through this form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

So, I am working on this simple problem where I have a search form and I want the user to enter the search term. After clicking enter, the user should go to a google appliance page to see the search results. Everything works fine, but the search does not work in one specific instance and I don't know how to take care of this issue. Basically, the search works https://www.efg.ijk/?# if I have '?#' in my URL. Therefore, it does not work the very first time I try because my URL looks like https://www.efg.ijk/. However, after sending first search request, the URL becomes https://www.efg.ijk/?# and subsequent searches work fine.

Here is the code that I have written:

```
<form id="search-nav" action="#">
                    <input class="search-field" placeholder="Search…" value="" title="Search:">
                    <button class="search-submit">
                            <span class="fa fa-search">
                                <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                            </span>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

To redirect, AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".search-submit" ).on( "click", function()  {
    $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            var value= $(".search-field").val();
            $(".search-field").val("");
            window.location.href =URL + value;
            //URL is the address and I am appending the query using value.
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This AJAX code makes no sense.  You're not providing anything for the actual AJAX request (such as, you know, a URL) and in the success callback you're just ignoring the response and redirecting.  Why are you using `$.ajax()` at all?  I suspect this is really the root of the problem you're seeing.

Comment: why don't you use URL as `https://www.efg.ijk/?#` instead of 'https://www.efg.ijk/' or else append `?#` while navigating to location, make it `window.location.href = URL+'?#'+value;` itwill work for you.

Comment: @David I understand what you are saying, but a simple request to location.href does not let me redirect to another url. Also, I searched on the web and every example suggests that I should use Ajax to redirect the url.

Comment: @VikashMishra So, The URL in my Ajax is different location. It is not www.efj.ijk. The problem is that I can't go from www.efj.ijk to the URL in my Ajax request unless I have '?#' appended in my www.efj.ijk url.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: I really don't think you *do* understand, or you'd see why the code you've written makes no sense at all.  What specifically *should* this code be doing?  Copying and pasting segments of code from the internet isn't getting you very far, step back and describe what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma please elaborate your requirements and what are the issues with proper description and screenshot or any error that you get.

Comment: Okay! If I use a direct redirection using location.href on button click it does not take me to the URL that I want to go. It does not matter if I use get or post method. Therefore, I need a ajax request to redirect me to the URL. That's why I chose to go that way after experimenting a number of way that didn't use AJAX. If I don't use AJAX, then I stay on the same page and my redirection won't work. I understand that I am not properly using the AJAX, but nothing else is working for me. I did not copy anything, and I would love to hear how you would do this problem Thanks :)

Comment: @VikashMishra Okay so the only error I am getting is that the AJAX redirect me to the error segment instead of success segment if I don't have '?#' attached at the end of my URL(www.efg.ijk) where the search box is located. After hitting success, I want to go to another URL. I understand that Get method appends ? at the end of the URL, but I tried post and it didn't work for me. I know I am using AJAX wrong and there is no need for it, but nothing  is redirecting me to the URL I want to go to. Also, I tried using the post and get methods and use direct href on button click, but it didn't help.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma: `"If I use a direct redirection using location.href on button click it does not take me to the URL that I want to go"` - That sounds like it would make for a good Stack Overflow question itself. `"It does not matter if I use get or post method"` - Makes no sense. A redirect is *always* a GET. `"I need a ajax request to redirect me to the URL"` - Makes no sense. AJAX is meant specifically *not* to direct to a new page, but to stay on the same page. Basically, you've made a mess of this code. Can you demonstrate the *original* problem before you tried (incorrectly) using AJAX?

Comment: Okay! The problem is that I have a search box on one page and I need to redirect the user to another page which is a Google Appliance page where I am trying to show the user results of his Query. In My example, the URL under the AJAX call is the google appliance URL where I want the user to go.

Answer (score 0):

Although even after so much of explanation, I am unable to understand the exact requirement, still I will suggest you little changes, Please try if it works for you

**HTML Part**

```
                    <input class="search-field" placeholder="Search…" title="Search:">
                    <button class="search-submit">
                            <span class="fa fa-search">
                                <span class="sr-only">Search</span>
                            </span>
                    </button>
```

**JQUERY Part**

```
  $( ".search-submit" ).on( "click", function()  {

            var value= $(".search-field").val();
            $(".search-field").val("");
            window.location.href =URL +'#'+ value;
            //URL is the address and I am appending the query using value.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Google is sunsetting the Google Search Appliance so you might want to start looking at alternatives. Here is one option and they are doing free trials http://www.yippyinc.com/google-search-appliance-replacement